# Односвязный список с++ - указатель next

Tags: c++, указатели, список

Из текстового файла - аргумента командной строки принимается файловый поток. В нем слова, разделенные переносом строки, и начинающиеся с одной из трех знаков(+,-,?). Внутри реализуем односвязный список.

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <cstdio>
#include  <cstring>

using namespace std;

class List
{
public:
        void chk_list();
        char word[30];
        List * next;
        List * head;
        List();
};

List::List()
{
        head = NULL;
}

void ShiftLeft(char buffer[30])
{
        for(int i = 0; i<30 ; i++)
        {
                buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
        } 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int count = 0;
        List * stuff;
        ifstream input_file(argv[1]);
        char buffer[30];

        while(!input_file.eof())
        {
                if(buffer[0] == '+')
                {       
                        ShiftLeft(buffer);
                        strcpy(stuff->word, buffer);
                        cout<<"добавлено :   "<< stuff->word <<"\n"
                        stuff=stuff->next;
                        count++;
                }

                input_file>>buffer;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Проблема с указателем next. Цикл, вынесенный ниже выполняется один раз и даже вносит в список и выводит первое слово, при повторном прохождении показывает Segmentation Fault при первом упоминании "`stuff->word`" в `strcpy()`. Причем, если перед `strcpy()` попробовать вывести "`stuff->word`" , то запорется на выводе, то есть segmentation fault возникает при первом его упоминании.

```
 while(!input_file.eof())
        {
                if(buffer[0] == '+')
                {       
                        ShiftLeft(buffer);
                        strcpy(stuff->word, buffer);
                        cout<<"добавлено :   "<< stuff->word <<"\n"
                        stuff=stuff->next;
                        count++;
                }

                input_file>>buffer;
        }
```

Как исправить это и в чем секрет указателей на следующий элемент списка. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что здесь не так, Вы поймёте, если почитаете для чего нужен оператор new.

Comment: `ShiftLeft(buffer); strcpy(stuff->word, buffer);` это конечно шедевр. `strcpy(stuff->word, buffer+1);` мягко говоря проще. Так что просто почитать простые учебные пособия по теме указателей точно не помешает. Ну и про new вам уже сказали, память под объекты надо выделять.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Назначение данной функции непонятно

```
void ShiftLeft(char buffer[30])
{
        for(int i = 0; i<30 ; i++)
        {
                buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
        } 
}
```

И более того эта функция является источником неопределенного поведения программы, так как при `i` равным `29` происходит обращение к памяти за пределами массива в предложении

```
buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
                   ^^^^
```

Если вы делаете это, чтобы убрать ведущий символ из набора `"+, -, ?"`, то в этом нет никакой необходимости, так как исходную строку можно было бы копировать в список не с первого символа, а со второго, как, например,

```
strcpy( stuff->word, buffer + 1 );
```

Естественно вместо символьных массивов было бы лучше и надежнее использовать стандартный класс `std::string`

Список лучше определить следующим образом:

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char word[30];
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr;
public:
    void chk_list();
};
```

Можно было бы конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания определить как удаленные.

Цикл в main также является источником неопределенного поведения программы, так как переменная `buffer` была не инициализирована

```
//...
char buffer[30];

while(!input_file.eof())
{
    if(buffer[0] == '+')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...
```

Для чтения слов лучше использовать метод `getline`, задавая размер символьного массива. Например,

```
while ( input_file.getline( buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) )
//...
```

Вам также следует в определения списка добавить метод, который будет включать новые элементы в список.

Вы должны определиться: то ли вы добавляете новые элементы в начало списка, то ли в конец списка. То, что вы делаете сейчас, просто записывая

```
stuff=stuff->next;
```

естественно является некорректным. Вы не выделяете память для нового элемента.